# How to test membership in a node's children, grand-children, great-grandchildren, etc.?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm not sure I'm using the right language here, but given a particular node in a tree, how would I test membership for children, grand-children, etc.?

```
     1
   /   \
  2     3 
 / \   / \
4   5 6   7
```

Basically, I have genealogical records in a csv file tagged as a tree. Given a particular person, I'd like to see the records of people who are ancestors of that person. In this case, given "2", I'd get a list of 2,4,5. Given "1", I'd get a list of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. TY.

Edit: I think this question was poorly-phrased, my apologies. By "language" I meant terms like "node" and "tree" that I may be using incorrectly. I said "test membership" because I wasn't sure that this was a recursion question, and perhaps the same result could be arrived at via math. I've also confused ancestors and descendants. What I was looking for was guidance on how to get a branch of a tree beginning at a certain node. The order of the result doesn't matter in this case. I'll look up the different traversal options, thanks!

Comment: Does the order of the output matter? It's a lot more natural to get either `1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7` (a pre-order traversal) or `4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 3, 7` (an in-order traversal) when starting from the root node. The term you're using "test membership" seems like a complete red-herring.

Comment: You're a lot more likely to receive helpful answers if you share what you've tried so far, and ask specific questions about issues you have encountered. Consider adding code and errors to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically do this recursively.

If your tree structure is made up of Person object instances defined as follows:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,mother=None,father=None):
        self.name   = name
        self.mother = mother
        self.father = father
```

An ancestor property can be defined recursively:

```
    @property
    def ancestors(self):
        result = [self.name]
        if self.mother: result += self.mother.ancestors
        if self.father: result += self.father.ancestors
        return result
```

output:

```
person7 = Person("7")
person6 = Person("6")
person5 = Person("5")
person4 = Person("4")
person3 = Person("3",person6,person7)
person2 = Person("2",person4,person5)
person1 = Person("1",person2,person3)

print(person2.ancestors) # ['2', '4', '5']
print(person1.ancestors) # ['1', '2', '4', '5', '3', '6', '7']
```

*Note that it is a bit weird to include the person in a list of 'ancestors' but the method is compliant with your expected result*

Comment: "a bit weird"  <- agreed. Perhaps it would have been more clear to ask for a branch beginning at a certain node. The usage examples are helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're asking about language. This question is language-agnostic.

If a node of a tree is implemented as:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Then all you need to do is given a `node`:

```
def family(node: Node):
    children = [node.left, node.right]
    grandchildren = [(n.left, n.right) for n in children]
    return children, grandchildren
```